# C# regex get string beetween numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple string that would look like

```
string text = "1\t2:3|5"
```

So my goal is to get the chars between numbers something like:

```
string[] result = {"\t", ":", "|"}
```

I tried to bite this by getting numbers first

```
 Regex.Matches(text , "(-?[0-9]+)").OfType<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

And then use this regex pattern

> /[^ \w]/g

Well I am getting symbols but "\t" is splitted to "" and without "t", how to regex this?

Comment: Why not like `(?<=\d)\D+(?=\d)` https://regex101.com/r/I6B11i/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `Regex` or `String.Split` - result is same

```
char[] separators = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };        
var splitResult = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);        

var matchesResult = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\d)\D+(?=\d)").Select(w => w.Value).ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/csj1f6